# How to build a Url with multiple query (?) params with CakePHP 3

Tags: cakephp, url-routing, cakephp-3.0

I'm working in a redirection for autocomplete some fields, and I'm doing this with simple javascript.

I wanted to print a URL without A tag, then I used Url builder. I've seen documentation and reviewed source code for this method in Router class but I see something that I can't understand.

All works right when I use Url builder with this code:

```
<?= $this->Url->build(['controller' => 'places', 'action' => 'add', '?' => ['event_id' => $event->id]]) ?>
```

Url genetared is:

```
/places/add?event_id=1
```

But, when I add more params in ? query, I get a & in url, but I didn't find in docs something for elimitate special chars filter.

```
<?= $this->Url->build(['controller' => 'places', 'action' => 'add', '?' => ['from' => 'events','id' => $event->id]])
// Generates:    /places/add?from=events&amp;id=1
// I want:       /places/add?from=events&id=1
 ?>
```

Is there an option to get & without &? If I put all in one string, I get UTF codes %5D and those. I'm using url in a javascript window.open, then I'm not printing in html body.

I see line 597 in http://api.cakephp.org/3.0/source-class-Cake.Routing.Router.html#509-646, but I don't understand if $url = static::_applyUrlFilters($url); code is changing something.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The URL helper is ment to be used for generating URLs for use in markup contexts, therefore they are being entity encoded using the `h()` function.

In case you need the plain URLs, don't use the URL helper, but the `Router::url()` method instead.

```
use Cake\Routing\Router;

Router::url([
    'controller' => 'places',
    'action' => 'add',
    '?' => [
        'from' => 'events',
        'id' => $event->id
    ]
]);
```